# Is playing Age of Empires Halal?

Tags: halal-haram, game

It's a strategy video game. Please only those who knows the gameplay answer this.

Answer (score 0):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

As Salaamu 3laykum,

I hope you are doing well. So here are the following ahadith that mention about images (animate beings).

Hadith #1

> Abu Talha, a companion of ALLAAH's Messenger (ﷺ) and one of those who fought at Badr together with ALLAAH's Apostle told me that ALLAAH's Messenger (ﷺ) said. "Angels do not enter a house in which there is a dog or a picture" He meant the images of creatures that have souls. (Bukhari)

Hadith #2

> "The Messenger of ALLAAH [SAW] said: 'Whoever makes an image will be commanded on the Day of Resurrection to breathe the soul into it but he will not be able to do so.'" (Nisai)

Hadith #3

> 'Aishah said: "The Messenger of ALLAAH [SAW] went out, then he came in, and I had hung up a curtain on which there were (images of) horses with wings. When he saw it, he said: 'Get rid of it.'" (Nisai)

Hadith #4

> "Jibril, peace be upon him, asked permission to enter upon the Prophet [SAW] and he said: 'Come in.' He said: 'How can I come in when there is a curtain in your house on which there are images? You should either cut off their heads or make it into a rug to be stepped on, for we Angels do not enter a house in which there are images.'" (Nisai)

Age of empires uses full figures in the game. The game involves moving figures which would be impermissible. We should all abstain from these types of games including those movies that are animated. Now an exception is made if this were a kids game under a certain age. The permissibility can come from these ahadith:

> Aisha (Peace and Blessings Upon Her) said: I used to play with the dolls in the presence of the Prophet, and my girl friends also used to play with me. When ALLAAH's Messenger (ﷺ) used to enter (my dwelling place) they used to hide themselves, but the Prophet would call them to join and play with me. (Bukhari)

> When the Messenger of ALLAAH (ﷺ) arrived after the expedition to Tabuk or Khaybar (the narrator is doubtful), the draught raised an end of a curtain which was hung in front of her store-room, revealing some dolls which belonged to her. He asked: What is this? She replied: My dolls. Among them he saw a horse with wings made of rags, and asked: What is this I see among them? She replied: A horse. He asked: What is this that it has on it? She replied: Two wings. He asked: A horse with two wings? She replied: Have you not heard that Solomon had horses with wings? She said: Thereupon the Messenger of ALLAAH (ﷺ) laughed so heartily that I could see his molar teeth.

**Have a Nice Day!**

**Note #1:** If you downvote my answer, please be courteous and say why you downvoted in a comment below.

**Note #2:** This is my own personal answer that I have derived from what I have researched.